# New ubuntu user gets "mkvirtualenv: command not found" error

Tags: django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I was able to run a test Django application after installing all the required software.

I was able to use mkvirtualenv and create two test apps that worked as required.

I then decided to create another user in Ubuntu. This user does not possess Sudo privileges because I wanted to secure the environment.
With this newly created user I get an error stating "mkvirtualenv: command not found".

My bashrc file has the following commits:-

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Running echo $WORKON_HOME results in the following:-

```
/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs
```

I'm not particularly sure what I need to do to have the ability to use mkvirtualenv with the new user.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The last line is wrong. Is it like this in `.bashrc`? Or have you pasted it twice?

Comment: Apologies. I pasted it twice. Output from the 'bashrc' file is 'export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'

Comment: Why have you installed Python and virtualenv in `/usr/local/bin` instead of `apt-get install python` and `apt-get install python-virtualenv`?

Comment: BTW, you can edit the question and fix the error.

Comment: I did not use those commands to install virtualenv and python. I used pip to install both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. Will using apt-get to install python and virtualenv fix this error?

Comment: I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)